# How to split special chars

Tags: c#

So I've a code, and I've been refining it to get it to work as best as possible. Now it works great, although I need it to filter through the entire sentence, regardless of any special chars wrapped around the word. For example, when I send the string:

```
JOIN GooGle | × ,,. ¬ hiring !HOteL, it is ++ !!free!! ,, ..!community;;+_
```

Banned words being `join, hiring, hotel, free, community` it won't detect the sentence above.

My code is:

```
public bool CheckSentence(string messageText.ToLower())
{
    var count = 0;
    string[] wordsInMessage = messageText.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, 
                                                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (WordFilter Filter in this._filteredWords.ToList())
    {
        count += wordsInMessage.Count(x => x == Filter.Word);
    }

    return count >= 3;
}
```

If I remove the special chars such as `!` from the words, it will work. I could just as easily add those characters to the char list, but surely there's a much simple method?

Comment: Yeah sweet, let's vote down my question. Cheers for the support.

Comment: I did not vote down, but you should start with what your code is supposed to do. "Banned words being join, hiring, hotel, free, community it won't detect the sentence above." is not a clear problem statement.

Comment: It's not being detected because of the special chars wrapped around it such as ! and ;

Comment: You  do some filter, i guess. Why just not use `Contains()`?

Answer (score 4):

This might do the trick for you Because it depends on your definition of special characters. I find that a whitelist rather than a blacklist is the best approach in most situations.

So now you are left with the string which does not have special characters and your code does the rest part.

```
public bool CheckSentence(string messageText.ToLower())
{
    messageText = Regex.Replace(messageText, @"[^a-z0-9 ]", "");
    var count = 0;
    string[] wordsInMessage = messageText.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, 
                                                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (WordFilter Filter in this._filteredWords.ToList())
    {
        count += wordsInMessage.Count(x => x == Filter.Word);
    }

    return count >= 3;
}
```

Comment: At what point will I add this code, and how will it it filter the string?

Comment: Awesome! So if I'm not wrong, this will replace special chars with an empty space? What chars will this replace, just those in the Regex?

Comment: You've included `@"[^\w\s]"` in the regex, will this only filter those characters? Because when I use ! and ; it's still not detecting the filtered word.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, if I wrap the word with ! or ; or _ it still bypasses it.

Comment: Just a little suggestion. Since the `messageText` is passed using `ToLower()` you do not need to specify `A-Z` in the `Regex` filter statement.

Comment: Absolutely correct @AmmarSalman Wonderful catch. :) Lemme update

Comment: Hi @Liam if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
string testData = @"JOIN GooGle | × ,,. ¬ hiring !HOteL, it is ++!!free!! ,, ..!community; ; +_";
List<string> bannedWords = new List<string>
{
    "join", 
    "hiring", 
    "hotel", 
    "free", 
    "community"
};

bannedWords.ForEach(word =>
{
    int startIndex = testData.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    if(startIndex == -1) return;
    testData = testData.Remove(startIndex, word.Length);
});
Console.WriteLine(testData);
```

Comment: FYI, you may want for check for `startIndex` being -1. `IndexOf` will return -1 if the string is not found. If the banned word is NOT found in the string... this will crash. I would add a check for `startIndex` being >=0 before you remove.

Answer (score 0):

I used two regular expressions, one to remove any characters that are not alpha characters, then another regular expression to remove extra spaces in the string. Then I set the original string to lowercase to match the banned words list. Then I simply split the string on spaces. Hope this helps.

```
static String input = "JOIN GooGle | × ,,. ¬ hiring !HOteL, it is ++ !!free!! ,, ..!community;;+_";
static Regex charOnly = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z ]");
static Regex extarSpaces = new Regex(@"\s{2,}");
static List<String> bannedWords = new List<String> { "join", "hiring", "hotel", "free", "community" };

static void Main(string[] args) {
  string originalString = charOnly.Replace(input, "");
  originalString = extarSpaces.Replace(originalString, " ");
  originalString = originalString.ToLower();
  string[] splitArray = originalString.Split(' ');
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.Length; i++) {
    if (splitArray[i] != null) {
      if (bannedWords.Contains(splitArray[i].ToString())) {
        count++;
        Console.WriteLine("Banned: " + splitArray[i].ToString());
      }
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("originalString: " + originalString);
  Console.WriteLine("splitArray Size: " + splitArray.Length);
  Console.WriteLine("Banned Words in string = " + count);
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```